# How can i post MQTT data to a blank webpage

Tags: node-red

I Would like to post data received over MQTT onto a blank HTML webpage, so that the only contents of that webpage is the original msg.payload sent over MQTT. For this I created the flow below.

[image: Image of Node-Red flow]

I have tried to use the GET and POST functions, and tried the websocket function too, but have had no luck, I am hoping someone could tell me where im going wrong. The intended webpage is simply a webpage displaying the temperature value.

Edit:
[image: Picture of what happened when i attempted to use the GET function, after setting global.temp as the msg.payload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very close. One easy way is like shown below.

First, you save the payload to a flow context variable. I used inject nodes but you will replace by an MQTT node.

Secondly, you use an HTTP in node to trigger the flow that will read the flow context variable to `msg.payload`.

When you point your browser to the endpoint `/mytemp` you will see the temperature.

```
[{"id":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","type":"tab","label":"Flow 4","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"a35c9258.340b1","type":"debug","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":570,"y":120,"wires":[]},{"id":"fb8bcf33.015ee","type":"http in","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"/mytemp","url":"/mytemp","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":180,"y":220,"wires":[["7bb7b19.2efd75"]]},{"id":"7bb7b19.2efd75","type":"change","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"mytemp","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"mytemp","tot":"flow"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":340,"y":220,"wires":[["8b54468f.82d758","2b02d89.dfec028"]]},{"id":"8b54468f.82d758","type":"debug","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":550,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"a691c7d8.da5d78","type":"inject","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"","topic":"","payload":"21","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":190,"y":120,"wires":[["3af6ea2f.2c0476"]]},{"id":"3af6ea2f.2c0476","type":"change","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"flow.mytemp","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"mytemp","pt":"flow","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":370,"y":120,"wires":[["a35c9258.340b1"]]},{"id":"2b02d89.dfec028","type":"http response","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":570,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"2f1ab064.3b768","type":"inject","z":"6eba3ed8.e29ba","name":"","topic":"","payload":"33","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":190,"y":160,"wires":[["3af6ea2f.2c0476"]]}]
```

[image]